# Verb, gerund or participle?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a gerund and a participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66/whats-the-difference-between-a-gerund-and-a-participle)

> The doctor was *talking* to the patient.

Here 'talking' is used as verb, gerund or participle?

Comment: Define those terms, and you’ll have your answer.  Note that gerunds and participles are still verbal forms, even when acting as substantives or modifiers.

Comment: If you want a name for _talking_, [it depends](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) on the construction. This is the Progressive construction. That's the only useful name.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you normally call things in grammar. It can either be a **verb** in +ing form or a present **participle**.

- verb in +ing form (past progressive):

> The doctor was *talking* to the patient.

- present participle

> The doctor was *talking* to the patient.
>
> The *talking* bird is a mynah. (used as an adjective)

- On the other hand, a gerund would be like this:

> The doctor enjoys *talking* to patients.
>
> *Talking* to patients helps.

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to include *The doctor was talking to the patient.* **twice**.

Comment: I did :-) I wanted to show how "talking" can either be called a verb in v+ing or a present participle by different people