# How do you differentiate between a transitive verb and a noun?

Tags: nouns, transitive-verbs

I have several components in a piece of software I am working with and we want to select names that are nouns which describe the components.

We have the following names:

- Automation
- Retrieval
- Parsing

It has been brought up by a team member that "parsing" is a transitive verb and not a noun and that we should select a new name to maintain consistency.

Can the word "parsing" be used as both a noun and a transitive verb?

Why is "parsing" not a noun?

Comment: It's a noun.  Go ahead and use it.

Comment: I originally thought that it was. Upon looking through several dictionaries I have found that there is no alternate definition or classification that indicates it is a noun. Why is that?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66/whats-the-difference-between-a-gerund-and-a-participle

Comment: Tell your colleagues that 'parsing' is a gerund: the '-ing' form of a verb employed as a noun. And point out that their other terms are also constructed by adding a suffix to a verb: *automate*, *retrieve*.

Comment: No word that ends in *-ing* is a verb.  All of them are either present participles or gerunds.  A participle is an adjective formed from a verb and a gerund is a noun formed from a verb.  In this case, *parsing* is most definitely a noun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might like to tell your fellow team member that the Oxford English Dictionary records *parsing* as having been used as a noun since the sixteenth century.

Comment: Where could one verify this online without paying for a subscription?

Comment: Here’s the OED’s earliest citation. It’s from Roger Ascham’s ‘Scholemaster’, published in the late sixteenth century: ‘Plaine construinge, diligent parsinge.’

Answer (score 2):

The noun form of *parse* is, well, *parse*. NOAD gives the following description:

> Computing: an act of or the result obtained by parsing a string or a text.

So how do you use *parsing* as a noun? The gerund form of a verb could be used as a noun. Here are some examples:

> Run: (runs, running ; past ran |ran|; past participle run). Noun: Run.

So you could say *a cross country run.* Or

> *Running* keeps you healthy. Here running is used as a noun. Or
>
> *Parsing* is a common term used in psycholinguistics when describing language comprehension.(Wikipedia)

Comment: "Parse" as a noun has a different meaning from "parsing" as a noun; and it seems clear that the former is not what the OP wants.