# Gerund ending in -ings?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, gerunds

Examples:

- Savings
- Shavings
- Drippings

Are these gerunds?

I found some resources (below) that don't seem to provide definitive answers.

- [Page 57](http://books.google.com/books?id=G3na3U3PGy4C&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=%22shavings%22+gerund&source=bl&ots=bkOXgwUJNl&sig=YtDaCK0hA_mjbv4-8JFesSCI6QE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MeVyU4_MJM2Mqgb49oJo&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22shavings%22%20gerund&f=false)
- [Page 320](http://books.google.com/books?id=QD_pVOM4Q3cC&pg=PA320&lpg=PA320&dq=%22has+acquired+a+completely+concrete%22&source=bl&ots=l-jC0FMSNk&sig=mJPdDuArg4Tal3N8FRGJ1TTjosA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AuZyU9OCGNCmyATKrILICw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22has%20acquired%20a%20completely%20concrete%22&f=false)

Comment: After Jespersen, how's it still not definitive? "It can form a plural: *his comings and goings, sayings and doings* ..."

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/497286/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is so confusing, that if I placed itmes in the wrong category, please correct it for me!*

Three types of English words ending with "ing":

- present participle
- gerund
- verbal noun

#### Present participles

1. can be used as adjectives.

   - **Running** dogs don't die.
   - The **painting** professionals are painting the house.
2. are present activities that can describe the state of perpetrator of the activity

   - They are **running**
   - The cows are **coming** home
   - The gravy is **dripping** in the oven.
   - The painting professionals are **painting** the house.
   - She was **painting** Mona Lisa.

#### Gerunds

1. They are a noun form. They are not used as adjectives.

   - They enjoy **smoking**.
   - I enjoy **swimming** and **painting**.
2. They can be transitive to a direct object. But they are non-prepositional to the object.

   - They like **painting** trees.
   - Painting professionals like **painting** professionals. = Painting professionals like to paint professionals.
   - They enjoy **smoking** weed.
   - Mrs Gujeratnam's hosting a party is **exciting** her students.
   - She enjoys **painting** Mona Lisa.
3. They can be a possession of the perpetrator.

   - I appreciate your **walking** my dog.
   - The painting professionals' **painting** professionals are painting professionals off the street.
   - Mrs Gujeratnam's **hosting** a party is exciting her students.
   - Her **swimming** is very versatile.
   - Her **painting** Mona Lisa is her **enjoying** life.

#### Verbal nouns

They are

1. finalized derivatives of gerunds and participles.

   - The sold me a fake **painting**.
   - Please put the bowl of gravy **drippings** in the freezer.
   - ***Sinking*** is a disaster movie.
   - Look at all your **shavings** in the sink. What a mess!
   - I have $3million in my bank **savings**.
   - The gasket is shielded by a steel **housing**.
2. Cannot be transitive to a direct object, but requires a preposition

   - Da Vinci's **painting** of Mona Lisa is worth half a billion dollars.
   - The gasket is shielded by a steel **housing** compartment.
3. They are usable as adjectives but only due to their finalized verbal nouns.

   - The **dripping** pan in the oven is rusty.
   - The **swimming** pool is open to public.
   - I have $3million in my **savings** bank account.

#### Gerunds again

There are two modes of gerunds:

1. adverbial gerunds, modifiable by adverbs.

   - Their **rowing** quickly is exciting the crowd.
2. adjectival gerunds, modifiable by adjectives.

   - Their quick **running** saved the day and won them a medal.

Comment: There are gerunds which are not verbal nouns. There are verbal nouns that are not gerunds. All verbal nouns due to progressing participation (ending with "ing") are gerunds.

Answer (score 1):

They are *verbal nouns,* i.e. ones to which an aura of verbiness still clings because of the fact that a particular action or process was necessary to bring them into existence. (For more info, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun), and/or Google "verbal noun".)

Comment: Gerunds do function as nouns, including as verbal nouns. So the question remains "are they gerunds?" per OP.

Comment: @Kris - You're quite right. I neglected to mention that they are nouns derived from gerunds.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not gerunds, and one clear indication is that they can be pluralized, which means they are actually nouns. Gerunds refer to the act of performing the verb itself, and cannot be pluralized, nor modified by the article ("the") or adjectives. The last characteristic is another way to distinguish between gerunds and pure verbal nouns.

### Gerunds

I was tired from **shaving** the wood.

**Dripping** occasionally is unavoidable.

I heard the tap's **dripping**.  [Some use "tap dripping" but it is less formal.]

I look forward to your **visiting** my family.  [Some use "you visiting ..." but it is less formal.]

Kindness is **helping** others in need.

**Forming** gerunds is simple.

**Saving** for the future is prudent.

### Not gerunds

I got tired **shaving** the wood.  [participle modifying "I"]

I have plenty of wood **shavings**.  [concrete noun modified by "wood"]

Occasional **dripping** is unavoidable.  [pure verbal noun modified by "occasional"]

I heard the **dripping** tap.  [participle modifying "tap"]

I was just **helping**.  [participle that is part of the verb "was helping"]

The **forming** of gerunds is simple.  [pure verbal noun modified by "the"]

Having **savings** for the future is prudent.  [concrete noun]

You might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English for more details and examples.