# How to choose between "spatial" or "spatially"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I'm writing my thesis and I need help with the title, here it is:
*Improved seam merging for temporally and spatially video resizing with structure and motion preservation*
I am not sure about the adverbs: it is correct to say *spatially video resizing* or *spatial video resizing* (or both of the alternatives are wrong)?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is based on an ill-formed sentence.

Comment: It's not a "sentence" per se, it's a title. Would you complain that the lack of a verb in "Uncle Tom's Cabin" makes it an "ill-formed sentence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to put on your mathematical hat. Which shouldn't be hard for you, should it?

"spatially video resizing"?

You need to decide which it is that you want

- you want *spatially* to describe *video* = use adjective *spatial* instead
- you want *spatially* to describe *resizing* = use adverb *spatially*

Now, perform your equation factorization. Which of the following is it?

#### 1.1

completed task improving seam merging, which temporally & spatially resizes videos.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{
 {{temporally and spatially} resizing}
 videos
}
using
{{structure and motion} preservation}
```

#### 1.2

completed task improving seam merging, for a single video whose resizing is characterised by its temporal & spatial dimensions.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{
 {{temporally and spatially} resizing}
 video
}
using
{{structure and motion} preservation}
```

#### 2.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{{temporally and spatially} resizing}
{
 videos
 that have
 {{structure and motion} preservation}
}
```

#### 3.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{
 resizing
 {temporal and spatial}
 videos
}
using
{{structure and motion} preservation}
```

#### 4.0.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{
 resizing
 {
  {
   {temporal and spatial}
   videos
  }
  that have
  {{structure and motion} preservation}
 }
}
```

#### 4.1.

```
Improved
{
 {seam merging}
 for
 {
  resizing
  {
   {
    {temporal and spatial}
    videos
   }
   that have
   {{structure and motion} preservation}
  }
 }
}
```

#### 5.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{
 resizing
 {temporal and spatial}
 videos
}
by preserving
{structure and motion}
```

#### 6.

```
{Improved {seam merging}}
for
{
 resizing
 {temporal and spatial}
 videos
 that preserves
 {structure and motion}
}
```

If your intention is none of the above, then factorize the structure until it does convey your intention.

Also note that 4.0 and 4.1 convey the same message, using the same order of words, but with different structures. Such alternative structures is also available for the other points 1 - 3, 5 - 6.

#### Appendix

To answer a further question ...

Principle of proximity in the use of English compels placing related words as close as is beneficial towards showing their relationship.

Use either

- Temporally and spatially resizing of videos
- Temporal and spatial video-resizing

*Resizing* in *video-resizing* is a gerund, no longer a verb or a participle.

Pls refer to my write-up at [Gerund ending in -ings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170336/gerund-ending-in-ings/170377#170377) for an explanation between present participles, gerunds and verbal nouns.

A gerund is a noun form, the name of an action. A noun requires its descriptor to be an adjective rather than an adverb.

- Her **noisy complaining** is abruptly annoying our patrons.
- Her **abrupt annoying** of our patrons occurs when she is complaining noisily.

A participle is still a verb form. A verb requires its descriptor to be an adverb.

- Her noisy complaining is **abruptly annoying** our patrons.
- Her abrupt annoying of our patrons occurs when she is **complaining noisily**.

Comment: Alternative intention to #5. while preserving
{structure and motion}

Comment: Thank you for the really complete answer! The right choice is number 1 because spatially has to be used to describe resizing and not videos. Can I say "... temporally and spatially video resizing..." or should I say "...temporally and spatially resizing video..." ? Thanks!

Comment: #1 is wrong due to typo. I will add #1.1 with plural *videos*

Comment: There is a principle of proximity in the use of English that it is better to place related words as close as possible. *Temporally and spatially resizing of videos* vs *Temporal and spatial video-resizing*. I am adding explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's not an adverb you want because video resizing is a compound noun, so you want an adjective. The adjectives are "temporal" and "spatial" so it reads "...temporal and spatial video resizing..."