# Difference between Brand (noun) and Branding (gerund?)

Tags: verbs

I am writing for marketing client. Goal is to clearly define difference between the two terms. A BRAND (noun) is the collective set of perceptions existing about a company in the larger world. BRANDING is the actions a company takes to influence those perceptions. Is Branding simply a gerund in this case? That seems less, uh, active than the situation requires.

Comment: You apply *branding* to establish a *brand*.

Comment: Yes. The tool is called a _branding iron_ and its use is quite difficult and dangerous. The output of the iron is called the _brand_, and the process is called _branding_. Everything else is metaphoric use.

Answer (score 2):

In advertising marketing a brand is something you can point to such as a company and/or their product. Branding is about how you go about PROMOTING the brand by marketing and advertising.

Answer (score 2):

Understand that "brand" originates from cattle branding and the like, where the owner's mark was burned into the hide of the animal.

The original meaning of "brand" in commerce was precisely this owner's mark -- a trademark emblem or phrase, applied to (printed on) all the products produced by the mark's owner.  Thus Kellogg's prints a large, stylized "*K*" (or the stylized word "*Kellogg's*") on all of their breakfast cereal products -- that's their trademark or "brand".

This concept was then expanded to mean the "aura", as it were, surrounding the products bearing that brand.  Eg, Chevrolet and Ford both attempted to produce impressions of their automobiles as being made for "real people", whereas Cadillac and Lincoln (brands, oddly, from the same companies producing Chevrolet and Ford) sought to produce impressions of luxury and exclusivity.  These impressions became part of the conceptual "brands".

"Branding" (when not applied to livestock) thus means the development (or, often, fabrication out of thin air) of not just an emblem but the set of impressions that that brand is expected to represent.

Answer (score 2):

The modern use of *[brand](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brand)* and *branding* is a metaphorical application of the practice of *branding*, that produced a distinguishing mark of ownership on grazing livestock:

> Noun
>
> 2.0 An identifying mark burned on livestock or (especially in former times) criminals or slaves with a branding iron:
>
> Verb
>
> 1.0 Mark with a branding iron:

---

In this metaphorical application, *brand* is clearly used as a noun :

> 1.2 A particular identity or image regarded as an asset:
>
> *Your **brand** is your most valuable asset!*

*Brand* is also used as a verb in this metaphorical application:

> 1.1 Mark indelibly:
>
> 2.1 The promotion of a particular product or company by means of
> advertising and distinctive design:
>
> *We must **brand** ourselves as the sole provider of a unique service.*

---

The word *branding* can be complex, because as the *[progressive form](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/perfectforms/)* of the verb *brand*, it can be used in four different ways:

1. As a pure verb with the auxiliary *to be*:

> - Literal Application:
>
> *We are **branding** our cows down by the river.*
>
> *We were **branding** his cows before they were quarantined.*
>
> *We will be **branding** the calves as soon as they are weaned.*
>
> - Metaphorical Application:
>
> *We are **branding** our new product actively on the market.*
>
> *We were **branding** this new product until it was pulled from the market.*
>
> *We will be **branding** their new product as soon as the prototype is*
> *ready.*

2. The *[gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)* acquires noun functions while denoting the activity of the
   verb *brand*:

> - Literal Application:
>
> ***Branding** your heard discourages cattle rustling.*
>
> - Metaphorical Application:
>
> ***Branding** a service is the key to a successful startup in this market.*

3. As a *[participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle)*, *branding* functions as *adjective* (although some
   legitimately classify this as a *[noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)* using the
   gerund):

> - Literal Application:
>
> *His **branding** efforts paid off when we caught the thieves with his cattle.*
>
> - Metaphorical Application:
>
> *Our **branding** strategy has been quite effective.*

4. As a [*deverbal noun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun) it behaves completely like a noun:

> - Literal Application:
>
> *The **branding** of livestock has changed in the last century.*
>
> - Metaphorical Application:
>
> *The **branding** of your product will be a challenge because of the broad competition.*

The *branding **mark*** (noun: *brand*) is the outcome or product of *branding **activity*** (verb: *brand*) and they are inextricably connected in both the literal and the metaphorical application.

---

OED

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the differences between present participles, gerunds and verbal nouns: [Gerund ending in -ings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170336/gerund-ending-in-ings/170377#170377).

In quick but less precise description

1. participle = a verb inflected to be usable as a state/status descriptor.

   - She is *running*. She is *painting* the house. We are *dying* of hunger.
   - *running*/*painting*/*dying* describe the state/status of the subject perpetrating the verb.
   - The house is *painted*/*haunted*.
   - The *painted*/*haunted* house.
   - Her haunting the house is *annoying* the earth spirits. (*Annoying* describes the state of her haunting)
2. gerund = name/noun of the process/activity implementing the verb.

   - Her *haunting* the house is annoying the earth spirits.
   - Her *speaking* mannerisms are very distracting.
   - White tigers are a *dying* breed.
   - *Naming* babies is a community ritual for both Jews and Catholics.
3. verbal nouns are verbs that have been finalized into concrete nouns and can only be used as pure nouns.

   - The Mona Lisa is an entrancing *painting*.
   - Baby *naming* is a community ritual for both Jews and Catholics.

Therefore, you have to differentiate between the three modes of *branding*.

1. Participle:

   - She is *milking* the cow.
   - He is *posting* new brands onto social networks.
   - She is *branding* the cow.
   - Quick, run to the elevator. They are *branding* the new products at the 4th floor meeting now.
2. Gerund:

   - Her *milking* the cow is causing discomfort to the cow.
   - His job entails *posting* new brands onto social networks.
   - Her *posting* habits are a violation of corporate policies.
   - There is a *branding* meeting on the 4th floor, to determine marketing strategies and public profile of our new range of products.
3. Verbal noun:

   - Have you read the latest marketing review *posting*?
   - Is our *branding* the cause of the slipping in market share of our brands. Are the *strategies we employ on marketing* the brands defective?
   - *Branding* is a monthly online digest published by the company.