# Grammatical structure of "cease to exist"

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis

Merriam-Webster lists *cease to exist* as an example of a transitive use of the verb:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cease

Dictionary.com doesn't include the category transitive/intransitive verb, but it lists *cease to exist* as a use of the verb without an object (thus making it intransitive?):
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cease

I'm pretty rusty on my verb-verb interactions. I have:
cease (transitive verb)
*to exist (infinitive acting as direct object)*.

Comment: *To* is not a preposition here; it's part of the infinitive *to exist*. *Cease to exist* means "terminate existence". The latter formulation should make the transitivity clearer. It may be confusing if you consider a transitive verb one that transfers an acton. *Cease* might be considered the opposite of an action, since it means to stop acting, but grammatically, what's ceased is still the object of the verb.

Comment: Ok, I modified my last paragraph based on the information you provided. I understand intuitively how the phrase works, I just want to understand it mechanically as well. I guess my next project will be googling the "Transitive verb/ infinitive as object" structure.

Comment: There's an argument to be made here (and made by dictionary.com in particular) that *to exist* isn't so much the recipient of the verb's action as it is the verb's complement: it tells the nature of the cessation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will answer your main question, and then provide a hint of direction to your further research.

The phrase {cease to exist} can be structurally perceived either

1. Ceasing to-exist. Where the phrase {to-exist} is taken as a composite verb. In this context, {cease} is used transitively.
2. Ceasing in order to exist. e.g. He ceased, to exist. In this context, {cease} is used intransitively.

The phrase {to exist} is due to a class of verb conjugate (actually, absence of conjugation) known as *infinitives*.

*Infinitives* are found in every language that has temporal verb inflection (i.e. time-based inflection or tenses). *Note that {temporal} means time-based, rather than being temporary.*

*Infinitives* are a subclass of *nonfinites*.

*Nonfinites* have the fundamental property of not being inflected temporally. Various subclasses of *nonfinites* are also non-conjugated in number, gender or any of the various categories of grammatical elements.

In English, a phrase or word can either be

- inherently structured as nonfinite
- incidentally used as non-finite due to an adjunct or auxiliary finite-verb, where rules against redundancy in the pairing of the two verbs strip off the finite mode of the main verb.

  - e.g., He will **eat** his hat.

The existence and usage of nonfinites is due to *functional modularity* (aka -laziness is the mother of inventive necessity). *Functional modularity* is excessively used in software programming, hardware, IC design, manufacturing processes, such that a particular concept is modularised into a function that would require/allow minimum or zero modification/inflection to be reused/deployed anytime and almost anywhere. Statelessness is a form of nonfiniteness.

Participles, gerunds and verbal-nouns are nonfinites
([Difference between Brand (noun) and Branding (gerund?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232460/difference-between-brand-noun-and-branding-gerund/232469#232469)).

Nonfinites facilitate virtuous laziness. For example, these nonfinite phrases do not need to be inflected temporally and/or numerically:

- He came here **to die**. They are coming here **to die**. She will come here **to die**. We might come here **to die**.
- The **painting** was yours. Now the **painting** is mine. Soon, the **painting** shall be hers.

A rather interesting class or plane of nonfinites are subjunctives. Imagine the mathematics of real and imaginary numbers, where in applied mathematics a number is usually a combination of real and imaginary. *Subjunctives* are the imaginary conjugate storylines to the *real* world - they operate in the imaginary realm. Like their mathematical counterpart, they are a continuum, with infinite possibilities of combination between real and imaginary worlds.

However, in those deprecating traditional schools of grammar, they had been struggling to deal with that continuum by classifying subjunctives into distinct buckets of quantization, buckets that they keep on increasing, like propositional, wishfulness, doubtfulness, contingency, impossibility, narcissistic, concession, exhortative, imperative, blah, blah, blah. Not aware that *subjunctivity* is actually a continuum.

The new mathematically precise perspective is not simply {transitiveness} of a verb, but its {valency} https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics).