# What do you call the grammatical element that describes the state of being of the subject?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Suppose we have these sentences:

```
1. Smiling, she offered me a hot cup of chocolate. 
2. Busy finishing my homework, I have no time to even think about video games.
3. Knowing there's little change of being selected, Tim did not try out for the team.
4. Having visited NYC, now I know what real cities are like
5. Happily, he took my advice.
```

In the 5 sentences above, we have gerunds (`"smiling"`, `"knowing there's little change of being selected"`), adjective (`"busy finishing my homework"`), verb participle form (`"having visited NYC"`), and adjective (`"happily"`) all **describing a certain state of being of the subject.**

What is the formal name for such a grammatical element/structure?

Comment: "Smiling" is not a gerund, it's a present participle. "Knowing there's little chance of being selected" is also not a gerund, it's a present participle phrase, as is "having visited NYC."

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170336/gerund-ending-in-ings/170377#170377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first four sentences start with what the *Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p291) calls a **participle clause**:

> A non-finite clause with an *-ing* form or *-ed* form as its principal
> verbal component. (Also called *participial clause*.) Examples:
>
> - Looking to neither right nor left, he marched out
> - Having been warned before, he did not do it again.

Sentence 5 does not have a participle clause, and is in fact ambiguous. I suspect that most readers would interpret *happily*, not as referring to the state of mind of the *he* taking the advice, but rather as expressing the writer's attitude to the fact that the *he* took the advice. This type of adverbial is called a **disjunct** (ODEG, p124).

To disambiguate the sentence *happily* needs to be repositioned: *He happily took my advice* or *He took my advice happily*.

---

As an aside, a participle clause that has a different (implicit) subject than the subject of the matrix clause is called a *misrelated*, *dangling* or *hanging* *particple*. One of the ODEG's examples is: *Sleeping in mine orchard, a serpent stung me (Hamlet, 1.5)*.

Comment: Yes, Shoe has it, although I've always heard this called a present participle *phrase*, not *clause*. The difference is that a clause contains both a subject and a predicate.

Comment: @William. In traditional grammar a clause has a subject and a finite verb, but in modern grammar the OP's examples would be called _non-finite clauses_: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause .

Comment: @Shoe: I understand what participle clauses and disjuncts are; what I'd like to know is if there is a shared terminology based on the function they serve: describing a certain state of being of the subject. What about the noun, `"a 13-year-old middle-schooler"`, in the sentence `"A 13-year-old middle-schooler, Timmy already received admission letters from top universities in the country including MIT and Stanford"`? Is it an implicit participle clause (maybe you can insert "Being" at the front)?

Comment: @Yibo. I would call "_a 13-year-old middle-schooler_" in your sentence a _fronted appositive_. If you add the participle _being_, it becomes a participle clause. I know of no specific term that designates the participle clause as "_describing a certain state of being of the subject_".

Comment: I think the term I'm looking for is "adverbial". Thanks.

Comment: Yibo. Yes, _adverbial_ is a hypernym of _participle clause_. The ODEG defines it thus: "_... adverbials are optional elements of clause structure that can be realized by phrases or clauses_." The ODEG includes the following example of an adverbial that fits your definition of a state of being: "_Though disappointed_, she said nothing."

Answer (score 1):

The are **[fronted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuity_(linguistics)) [adverbial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) [adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_%28grammar%29)**.

They are adjuncts because they are not arguments of the verb or any other predicator. They are adverbial because they convey background information about the verb/situation. They are brought to the front of the sentence to emphasise them.