# Correct use of gaining popularity

Tags: grammar

I am trying to write the following sentence but have some doubt on the use of `gaining popularity`

In contrast with other technologies, we decided to get rid of this technology in favor of gaining popularity agile-based systems.

Comment: "...in favour of agile-based systems, which are gaining popularity"

Comment: There are many other problems with the sentence such as misplaced modifier and pronoun error. However, the correct usage of "gaining popularity" is rightly mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing A to B, it is better to say

> In contrast to

rather than

> In contrast with

Because, *in contrast wit*h could imply being a cohort/accomplice in the contrasting action.

When describing a current state of affairs due to a past event, it is better to employ a continuing participle or the completed participle.

> we have decided to

or

> we are deciding to

rather than

> we decided to

When using participial-phrases, gerunds or verbal-nouns, it is better to treat such participial-phrases/gerunds/verbal-nouns as actual entities, according them the privilege of having an article

- in favor of **the** gaining popularity of agile-based systems
- in favor of **a** cat over **a** dog
- in preference for **the** refrigerator than **the** freezer

Therefore,

> In contrast to other technologies, we have decided to get rid of this technology in favor of the gaining popularity of agile-based systems.

Reference:
[Gerund ending in -ings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170336/gerund-ending-in-ings/170377#170377)