# Gerund and Participles

Tags: gerunds, participles

I need your expert skills to solve this confusion regarding the use of gerund and participles.

Here is the sentence
***Standing in the shallow end*, he would practice his arm movements.**

I want to know whether the introductory phrase is a gerund or a participle.

Comment: Probably it's a participle, because the clause is adverbial; it's equivalent to _(While (he was)) standing in the shallow end, he .._ The parenthesized elements may be deleted without changing meaning.

Comment: In traditional grammar, it's called a participle phrase because it has the same function as an adjective in that it is seen as _modifying_ "he". But that's nonsense; it's actually a participial **clause**, headed by the present participle "standing", in adjunct function. Clauses like this don't modify anything and hence are sometimes called supplementary adjuncts.

Comment: Like many adverbs, they modify the entire main clause.

Comment: But it's not an adverb, it's a clause in adjunct function. Supplementary adjuncts don't modify anything. They are semantically related to what is called their **anchor**, or as some grammars call it a 'host'. In the OPs example, the anchor is the main clause.

Comment: A *gerund* is a noun. That's not a noun. It would be a noun in the sentence *Standing in the shallow end and practicing your arm movements is a good way to learn to swim.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a gerund and a participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66/whats-the-difference-between-a-gerund-and-a-participle)