# Gerund vs Present Participle: "I was thinking about eating the apple."

Tags: gerunds, progressive-aspect, syntactic-analysis, participles, deverbal-nouns

A quick question that has popped up from talking with my German pen-pal. In the sentence:

> I was thinking about eating the apple.

Is *eating* there a gerund or a present participle?

If it is just:

> I was thinking about eating.

then that seems like a gerund to me. But adding *the apple* at the end has me confused.

Comment: _Thinking_ is a present participle; that's the form of the verb that's used in the progressive construction. _Eating_ could be a noun or it could be a gerund in _I was thinking about eating_ -- the speaker would probly know, and might make it obvious in speech, but a reader can't tell. Add a direct object, though, and _eating_ is unambiguously a verb, hence a gerund. Add a definite article, and it's a noun: _I was thinking about the eating (not the drinking)_. Without the context, one can't tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a gerund and a participle?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66/whats-the-difference-between-a-gerund-and-a-participle)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the basic differences between a gerund and a participle. I was just a little confused in this case. Reading around a bit, I think "eating the apple" is a gerund phrase, and "eating" is a gerund.
Confirm or deny?

Comment: @JohnLawler Pretty much answers the question; you should add it as an answer.

Comment: In the gerund clause `X`_'s eating the apple_, _eating_ is the gerund. But without a direct object, it's not possible to tell whether it's a gerund or not. Let me say that again -- with only an _-ing_ verb as the object, it may be a gerund or it may not be. Schrödinger's gerund, if you like. It's not automatically to be thought of as a gerund just because it ends in _ing_.

Comment: It has been argued that the gerund and the participle are not really distinct constructions: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2639 To avoid distinguishing them, we can refer to the "gerund-participle" form of a verb. (That doesn't mean that all *-ing* words are gerund-participles. The gerund-participle is a verb, but some *-ing* words are adjectives, like "exciting" in "a very exciting discovery", and some are nouns, like "hunting" in "the Hunting of the Snark".)

Comment: @suməlic *Notwithstanding* prepositions like *during*, which has its own strange story of surviving the extinction of its verb.

Comment: @sumelic, Thanks for the link to language log.  However, Liberman's post makes no sense to me.  Because Liberman as a child couldn't tell the difference between gerund and participle, I'm supposed to assume they're the same?  What kind of reasoning is that?

Comment: @GregLee: I'd assume you should look at Pullum and Huddleston for the reasoning

Comment: @sumelic, I looked below in the comments at Stephen C. Carlson's summarizing the CGEL "argument".  He says "OK, I've had a look at CGEL about abolishing the distinction between gerund and participle, and I have to admit that I didn't find the discussion particularly clear or persuasive."  Based on his account, I agree with him.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, John Lawler answered:

> *Thinking* is a present participle; that's the form of the verb that's used in the progressive construction. *Eating* could be a noun or it could be a gerund in *I was thinking about eating* -- the speaker would probly know, and might make it obvious in speech, but a reader can't tell. Add a direct object, though, and *eating* is unambiguously a verb, hence a gerund. Add a definite article, and it's a noun: *I was thinking about the eating (not the drinking)*. Without the context, one can't tell.
>
> In the gerund clause `X`*'s eating the apple*, *eating* is the gerund. But without a direct object, it's not possible to tell whether it's a gerund or not. Let me say that again -- with only an *-ing* verb as the object, it may be a gerund or it may not be. Schrödinger's gerund, if you like. It's not automatically to be thought of as a gerund just because it ends in *ing*.

Comment: Yes, but how does this bear on whether gerund and participle are distinct?

Comment: I think it's correct to say that _thinking_ is a present participle. But I don't think that you could say _eating_ in _I was thinking about eating_ can be a gerund (i.e., a verb) rather than a noun. Even without playing with a direct object, it's easy to see that it cannot be a gerund or a verb but only a noun, because you cannot say *_I was thinking about frequently eating_ but can only say _I was thinking about frequent eating_.

Comment: @JK2 [Quirk et al](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ApwSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=quirk+gradience+painting&source=bl&ots=ERBH9Uh1Db&sig=e_ul0i8h9S3TEbUdqWgx0uUDWRk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuocjLrdjSAhUmC8AKHSswBBsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=quirk%20gradience%20painting&f=false) prefer a gradience analysis of the noun ... verb distribution here. With sentences like _Bill's slowly painting the fence was beginning to annoy me_ being acceptable, I agree with them.

Comment: @Greg Lee 'Yes, but how does this bear on whether gerund and participle are distinct?' ___  JL says that _eating could be a noun or it could be a gerund in 'I was thinking about eating'_. He has chosen another terminology, but essentially he's saying << You can't tell whether 'eating' is verbier {JL's _gerund_, OP's _participle_} or nounier {JL's _noun_, OP's _gerund_} here. >> And he's been into linguistics a long time. (I never use 'gerund' as it has these conflicting definitions. I go with the Quirk/ACGEL splitting, deverbal noun ... ... ... ... obvious participle in ...

Comment: say 'he was eating'. ['Eating' is never a deverbal noun, unlike say 'painting/s' in  'his paintings are excellent'.]Though I get stuck in the middle.)

Comment: ...In the gerund clause X's eating the apple...@tchrist; Isn't it a phrase?  A clause's structure is perhaps different.  One'r writing an answer; one's receiving a reply, etc. are phrases.

Comment: I was thinking about...what? Like, I was thinking about my friend/ my career/ eating the apple.  It is a noun phrase

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, It's true that sometimes you can't tell whether an -ing word is a noun or a gerund.  Why is that a problem?  Sometimes you can't tell whether a flap is from a /d/ or from a /t/, but that doesn't mean there is no difference between /d/ and /t/.  There is no general requirement that we should be able to deduce what the correct analysis is in each and every example.

Comment: @Greg Lee You're changing what is being discussed. /  'How does this bear on whether X and Y are distinct?' makes no sense when someone has just said 'you can't tell whether this is X or Y in this case'. They're obviously tacitly claiming that X and Y must be distinct (renaming X and Y). // But as I say, I use a third terminology and a different  analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Present participle has a form of "be" verb before it.
Example:
I am eating (past simple: I was eating)
He / she is eating: (past simple:He / she was eating)

The present participle expresses an action that´s going on at a given period of time.
It could be:
Present participle:              I am eating.      (Happening now)
Future continuous:  I will be eating at 7:20pm.      (This will be happening at a given period of time in the future)
Past continuous:  I was eating at 7:30am   (This was happening at 7:30am)

Gerund has no "be" verb before it, unless it´s a question though.
Gerund can not use in the past, you´ll need an auxiliary verb before it to do so. This is because gerunds are nouns.
Some nouns derive their names from verbs, such are considered gerunds.

Some examples:

I love something. ("Something" in this sentence is a NOUN")

Now, let´s substitute the word "Something" for any other noun:

I love apple
I love football    (Football is an event, a sport an activity, a sport, a noun.)
I love people
I love eating       (This does not mean that I´m eating now)
I love fishing

Similarly,I was thinking about eating the apple falls in the same category

You think about "SOMETHING". "Something" is a "NOUN". Substitute the word "Something" for any other noun to make a complete sentence.

Example:

I was thinking about eating.
I was thinking about dancing.
I was thinking about life.
I was thinking about my family

I was thinking about eating ... ("the apple") is just a complement in this case.

I love dancing      (This does not mean that I even know how to dance, perhaps I just like watching it.)

I hope this does help.