# When an -ing verb is applied to describe a noun, is it always an adjective? (or something else)

Tags: verbs, adjectives

When an -ing verb is applied to describe a noun, is it always an adjective? (or something else)

For example: "A dancing ninja showed up today." - is "dancing" an adjective in this context? (In this case, referring literally to a ninja who dances.)

Specifically, in use: https://twitter.com/DrawmaticAR/status/1225527363489976320

Comment: Related [What is the difference between a gerund and a participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66/whats-the-difference-between-a-gerund-and-a-participle).

Comment: It also depends on context. A dancing ninja jumped up on the table. Versus: Our company provides dancing ninjas for your events.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.  It could mean two things.  The most likely is:-

> ... a Ninja (which is) dancing

In that case, *dancing* is a participle and so an adjective, qualifying the noun *Ninja*.

But, however improbably, it could also mean

> a Ninja **for** dancing

That is, our Ninja might be a strange sort of *dancing* instructor.  Unlikely, of course but grammatically possible.  And in that case *dancing* would function as a noun (a so-called *gerund*), by analogy with ‘cricket bat’, where ‘cricket’ is strictly a noun, but is serving a bit like an adjective.

Nevertheless, despite this grammatical hall of mirrors, ‘dancing’ in your phrase is in all probability an adjective.  Had you supplied a fuller context, we could be certain.

Comment: Updated with the context - What would the second case be called?

Comment: @ina People would assume, I think, that in that context ‘dancing’ is a participle, by analogy with a ‘dancing bear’.  But this is getting surreal.

Comment: @ina Tuffy has already written that 'dancing' in the second case is a gerund. But that is not a function name. 'Gerund' says that we have a verb form acting like a noun. The function of 'dancing' in the second case is called _[noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)_, _attributive noun_, _qualifying noun_, or _noun (pre)modifier_.

Comment: What about "a crying baby"?

Comment: @Lambie 'crying' in 'a crying baby' is also "type one". It's an active present participle and in this constellation it has the function of a participial adjective.

Answer (score 0):

"Dancing" in "dancing ninja" can be understood as either a verb or participial  adjective. The difference between participial adjectives (both -ed and -ing ones) and the corresponding verbs is not always clear-cut. In general, participial adjectives denote more stable properties of the noun referent. In other words, to read  "dancing"  in "dancing ninja" as an adjective, your ninja would need to be some sort of a professional or habitual  dancer. As suggested above, that is an unlikely but by no means an impossible reading.  So the only remaining way to understand the phrase is that ninja was dancing when he entered the place. The meaning of "dancing" is clearly verbal - it is a verb. Finally, word classes are defined with a view to be mutually exclusive . Verbs and adjectives are two separate word classes, which means that one cannot be the other. This applies to any word class  - each is defined as a set of words possesing its unique characterics and at the same time lacking characteristics unique for any other word clasd.

Comment: I would be interested in an example of a unique characteristic of, say, an adjective. And in how you would classify _smoking_ in, for example, _His smoking 20 cigarettes a day is damaging his health_.

Comment: It is important to keep in mind that, speaking in absolute terms,  it is rather a set of properties that makes a class distinctive and secondly, not all properties of the set are shared among all the members.  None of the main properties of adjectives is absolutely unique to them but they are unique to them in their specific environments. For example, a predicative element that can be graded cannot be anything other than an adjective. An element of a verb phrase (other than linking verbs) that can be graded cannot be anything else but an adverb.

Comment: I've updated with a link of the specific use. Basically, when you add the adjective "dancing" in front of a person noun, they will show up as a dancing character.

Comment: @shoe i would classify smoking as part of its trailing extended noun (?) "smoking 20 cigarettes a day..." - but i'm by no means an expert in this area and i'm also curious how that would be classified!

Comment: For a long time people struggled with the term gerund and what the term is supposed to entail. In Quirk's grammar you can find a sort of a spectrum intended to fine-grade the uses of the -ing form,  starting from what is clearly an -ing noun, through examples of a sort of a mongrel, called gerund, and ending with clear verbal ing forms. The term gerund is an example of what it looks like when there is a serious flaw in a grammatical model. Instead of analyzing the ing form in "his smoking 20 cigarettes" as a gerund, as was done before, it makes far more sense to think it as a verb.

Comment: The use of pronouns before the ING verb, such as his in your example, was used as the grounds for introducing this rather mystical half-breed gerund class. But the other form - "him" is used no less with ing forms, and is not used with nouns in that way,  so that would dispense with that argument. Him/his are pronouns understood as the subject of the following ing clause. "The smoking of cigarettes" is a noun phrase - articles are unique to nouns, and of-phrase a common noun modifier. On the other hand.,."Smoking cigarettes" is an ING clause, smoking is a verb -verbs take objects.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to explain your position. In cases such as my smoking example I don't share the need to make a definitive categorization: _Smoking_ here __is__ an noun, or _smoking_ here __is__ a verb. It is enough for me to say that it has a characteristic of a prototypical noun (it is preceded by a possessive pronoun) and also a characteristic of a prototypical verb (it has an object).

Comment: And as I mentioned in another thread, I am more interested in usage and grammaticality than classification. I don't see any particular advantage for my students to learn that _smoking_ is regarded by some grammarians definitively as a verb here.

Comment: Okay Shoe, it is really up to the person to decide to what extent or whether at all they will study language structure. Also hotly debated is the issue of the pedagogical value of grammar instruction. As for myself, I'm interested in grammar stuff, you could have guessed that by now :)