# Is the gerund and (present) participle form always the same (spelling)?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, participles

Are the participle and gerund form of a verb always technically the same and in all tenses (in the sense of spelling) or do deviations exist?

Reason is because I'm building a database and need to know if I need to store these in separate fields or if I can deduce their grammatical context from code.

Comment: CGEL, which many regard as the most authoritative work on grammar, groups 'both' under the term 'gerund-participials'. ACGEL has a N ... V  gradience from deverbal noun (note that 'etching', 'painting' etc can pluralise) with either quite a few or an undefined number of intermediate stages. I call them all ing-forms, in line with others not happy with the ill-defined term (qv) term  'gerund' in the first place. CGEL avoid it also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a gerund and a participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66/whats-the-difference-between-a-gerund-and-a-participle) (nohat's answer, line 3, though obviously CGEL and others disagree with nohat's analysis of ing-forms).

Comment: The present participle and the gerund always have the same spelling. But modern grammar doesn't distinguish the two, simply calling the _ing_ form a gerund-participle verb. Note that there is a genuine _ing_ form noun called a gerundial noun, not to be confused with the gerund-participle verb _ing_ form, cf. "They were criticised for killing the seals" (verb) vs "They were criticised for the killing of the seals" (gerundial noun).

Comment: The whole point of non-finite clauses (i.e. clauses headed by participles and infinitives) is to leave things inexplicit.  If I say, for example, 'skating on the lake', it isn't clear who was doing the skating, how many people there were, or when the action took place. You could expand it into: I was skating, they are skating, she will be skating, and so on. Only a subsequent (or previous) finite clause resolves the issue. Don't believe anyone who tells you that tense determines the correct choice of participle -- it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you @BillJ for your wonderful and spot-on comments. I just want to ask this in the context of your last comment (particularly this part _when the action took place_) : How is the sentence _Skating on the lake, the boys heard the ice crackle_ different from _While/When the boys were skating they heard the ice crackle_? Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Some (on this site) view the gerund-participle matter as a spectrum of nounal/verbal usage, rather than two separate categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the participle and gerund form of a verb always technically the
> same and in all tenses (in the sense of spelling) or do deviations
> exist?

Remember that verbs have different participles according to tense.

The gerund is *always* identical to the *present* participle. It is always *differently* spelled from the *past* participle.

The gerund itself has no tense because it is a noun equivalent.

Comment: +1 for a succinct answer! :)